# How work with github api to retrieve a repository's readme file?

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, github

I am trying to work with github api to get access to raw README.md file using `/repos/{owner}/{repo}/readme`, I am able to make the call using thunderclient in vscode and seeing the raw file.
[image]

but when I am making the same call from within my react application I am receiving a json object of this form

```
{
  "name": "README.md",
  "path": "README.md",
  "sha": "...",
  "size": 9,
  "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/contents/README.md?ref=master",
  "html_url": "https://github.com/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/blob/master/README.md",
  "git_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/git/blobs/592c92302634be24522f96f3ed6649f389f1aa0d",
  "download_url": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/master/README.md",
  "type": "file",
  "content": "IyBMaXRhY2kK\n",
  "encoding": "base64",
  "_links": {
    "self": "https://api.github.com/repos/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/contents/README.md?ref=master",
    "git": "https://api.github.com/repos/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/git/blobs/592c92302634be24522f96f3ed6649f389f1aa0d",
    "html": "https://github.com/anubhavadarsh/Litaci/blob/master/README.md"
  }
}
```

PS: I tried with a public repository that is not mine and I am able to get the raw readme, but my own repository still returns this.

Comment: `IyBMaXRhY2kK` is the base64 encoding of `# Litaci`, your client probably decodes it for you?

Comment: @BenjaminW., it can be the case but I am able to see raw .md file for other public repositories in my console, but it still isn't working for all my repositories.

Comment: How exactly do you retrieve your file, and the third-party file?

Comment: I am making the same fetch calls from within my application just changed the owner-name and repository-name, and it works for other repositories.

Comment: Did you set the content-type header?

Comment: Yeah, I set it to application/vnd.github.raw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [GitHub API docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents), the content of the file is returned encoded in base64. So basically you need to decode it in base64:

1. First install the package **js-base64** (run `npm i js-base64`)
2. Add the following code to the file where you're doing the GET request:

```js
const base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;
// Some code
const contents = base64.decode(res.content);
```

Comment: I was thinking of using `atob()` function builtin in javascript. As far as my understanding goes github returns an encoded content if the file is small enough but if it is large I receive raw readme.md file. How should I check when I need to decode the result and when I shouldn't?